# Finding the coordinate of a polygon

Tags: iphone, math, polynomial-math

I have height, width1 and width2 of a 4 sided polygon. how to detect mouse is clicked in that region.

Comment: Are you asking how to detect _any_ click in that region, or how to get the exact coordinates of a click in that region?

Comment: i want to detect  mouse click in that region. the sides are not of same size. the angles are also not same. if i know the coordinates at the corner, i can check mouse(x,y) is inside that range or not

Comment: Could you draw a simple picture to explain what parameters are known?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a "point in polygon" algorithm. This [link](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/) has a description and an implementation example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have 64 polygons (4 sided) in 8x8. They r not regular polygons. shall i apply this logic for them. i dont know the coordinates for all except each polygon width1, width2 and height

Comment: You can apply this logic only if you know all the coordinates. If you don't know where the polygons are, it's obviously impossible to tell whether a click has happened inside or not. If you have only one coordinate for each polygon you can probably calculate the others with your width and height variables before you run the point in polygon algorithm.